# Wordpress Admin Login no longer working (refreshing) after domain transfer and redirect

Tags: php, wordpress

The wordpress admin on my site www.troov.com/blog/wp-admin no longer works properly (it refreshes back to the same login page even when using the correct credentials). This occurred after I switched the domain from troov.co to troov.com

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is the url it's redirecting to www.troov.co/blog/wp-admin ?

I ask as a common cause of this type of behaviour is that the siteurl and home values in the wp_options table haven't been changed.

What steps did you take to change the URLs in your database when changing domains?

Comment: I initially changed it in the `wp-config.php` file, but then reverted it back to the original file after the change

Comment: Not sure what you mean Sean, perhaps you can post the relevant part of your wp-config file and also what the current values for siteurl and home are in the wp_options table?